# How to get back to STEM phD thesis after a long break?

Tags: phd, thesis, writing, literature-review, stem

**If one had to interrupt writing the phD-thesis** (for various reasons, that don't belong here):
**What is a good strategy to get back and finish the thesis?**

---

The writing would take place while working on a full-time job.
Assume that the supervisor already signalled to support this project with reading the 99%-final version and do the necessary formalities. The thesis is done in a STEM field, all lab work and calculations are finished. Before the interruption took place, the thesis itself was around half-written: out of four main sections, two are done, one almost done, one just an idea collection. Additional sections and Appendix are in a draft status, proofreading *etc.* has to be done as well.

One of the main concerns is the literature-review: As it currently is, it would be awfully outdated. Is it worth the effort to spend time on an extensive literature research (if so: how much?) or should one just draw a line and use the literature as it is (*i.e.* only the literature from before the interruption)?

The thesis is based on own, already published articles. Which should avoid running into plagiarism issues.

Comment: Actually I assumed, there was already a question that would cover this, but I couldn't find one. Bear with me and let me know, if this is a duplicate.

Comment: "only literature from before the interruption", you might plagiarize something unintentionally. A PhD thesis proves you know the literature in your field and made something new. Did you publish articles and most results before interruption?

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt Good point! Yes, the thesis more or less merges my already published articles.

Comment: Did your papers get a lot of citations? If not this saves you probably a lot of work ;-) Yet, without giving an overview in the introduction what happend in your field the past years and outlook how to build up on your work a thesis would feel incomplete to me.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt I had the same feeling of incompleteness, but was told from co-workers/friends I was too pedantic and in the current situation _quickly finishing_ was more important that _overly correctly finishing_.